# SWIFT2 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS down casting a class conforming to ErrorType

Tags: switch-statement, swift2, exc-bad-access, downcast

I have a simple Object hierarchy : RESTError with 2 attributes (httpCode and message), and 4 subclasses of it. One of the subclasses, RESTBusinessError has two additional fields.

I've simplified my code here below, but a RESTError variable (which is actually a RESTBusinessError) is used within a switch statement. Whenever I try to access the fields of the subclass, I've a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Any idea ? this looks obvious, and in the debug area, I can see that all my variables have the expected values.

I have this issue ONLY in case RESTError conforms to the protocol ErrorType.

Any Idea ?[image]

```
    var tmpError:RESTError;
    tmpError=RESTBusinessError(httpCode: 422, message: "error", businessCode: "003", businessMessage: "error");

    switch tmpError {
        case is RESTAuthorisationError:print("AUTH Error");
        case let bError as RESTBusinessError:
            let s1=bError.httpCode;
            let s2=bError.message;
            let s3=bError.businessCode;    // <- This systematically fails.
            let s4=bError.businessMessage;
            print("OK \(s1) \(s2) \(s3) \(s4)");
        default: print("default");
    }
```

Object Hierarchy is here below :

```
public class RESTError : ErrorType{
    var httpCode:Int
    var message:String

    init(httpCode:Int,message:String) {
        self.httpCode=httpCode;
        self.message=message;
    }
}

class RESTAuthorisationError : RESTError {}

class RESTServerError : RESTError {}

class RESTOtherError : RESTError {}

public class RESTBusinessError : RESTError {
    var businessCode:String
    var businessMessage:String

    init(httpCode:Int,message:String, businessCode:String, businessMessage:String) {
        self.businessCode=businessCode;
        self.businessMessage=businessMessage;
        super.init(httpCode: httpCode, message: message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `RESTBusinessError`?

Comment: Added in the main topic. If I remove the ":ErrorType" in the RESTError class, the issues goes away (but I need it so that I can throw my errors)

Comment: You don't appear to `init` the `ErrorType` base class?  (not even sure you need to, as I am no expert with Swift.  **EDIT** It's a protocol, so I doubt you need to).

Comment: It is actually a protocol... so I'm not supposed to call a init(), do I ?

Comment: No.  I am looking about and every example I see uses a `struct` or `enum` as the type that derives from `ErrorType`, so I am trying to find documentation to find out if it's even possible to use a `class`.

Comment: For the "throw" part or even the catch part, it all works fine... Here, in my API, I'm working in async mode, so I get an exception as response and I check what kind it is.

Comment: the trouble is somewhere else in you code ... create class conforming to ErrorType should works fine.

Comment: I am actually seeing this problem in my library now. It happens in a mixed objc/swift project, but pure swift project works fine. Were you able to find a solution @user3250215 ?

Answer (score -1):

check this example

```
import Foundation

func f() {
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("a", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
    var i: Int! = 0
    dispatch_async(queue) {
        i = nil
    }
    usleep(200000)
    print(i) // this is wrong
}
f() // debugger will stop here !!!!
```